# Linux Multithreading - threads do not produce any output as expected

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am learning multi-threading in Linux platform. I wrote this small program to get comfort with the concepts. On running the executable, I could not see any error nor does it print `Hi`. Hence I made to sleep the thread after I saw the output. But still could not see the prints on the console.

I also want to know which thread prints at run time. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void* print (void* data)
{
      cout << "Hi" << endl;
      sleep(10000000);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int t1 = 1, t2 =2, t3 = 3;
   pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
   int thread_id_1, thread_id_2, thread_id_3;
   thread_id_1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, print, 0);
   thread_id_2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, print, 0);
   thread_id_3 = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, print, 0);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Also, you realise you're making it sleep for over 100 days, right?

Comment: Nothing wrong with sleeping a 100 days. I do it every night.

Comment: True, but I was thinking that the OS may not flush the buffers and print the "Hi", and then OP would terminate the program, so that nothing prints.

Comment: Just an FYI: std::thread, mutex, async, etc. are part of the C++ standard since C++11 and give you a platform independent, idiomatic way to do multithreading in modern C++. IMO if you are learning multithreading for the first time there is no reason to prefer pthreads over the standards-compliant way. You can always go back and learn pthreads afterward, if you really want to. Unless you want to write in pure C, in which case you can ignore everything I just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main thread probably exits and thus the entire process dies. So, the threads don't get a chance to run. It's also possible (quite unlikely but still possible) that you'd see the output from the threads even with your code as-is if the threads complete execution before main thread exits. But you can't rely on that.

Call `pthread_join()`, which suspends the calling thread until the thread (specified by the thread ID) returns, on the threads after the `pthread_create()` calls in main():

```
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
```

You can also use an array of `pthread_t` which would allow you to use a `for` loop over the `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` calls.

Or exit only the main thread using [`pthread_exit(0)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html), which would exit only the calling thread and the remaining threads (the ones you created) will continue execution.

Note that your thread function should return a pointer or NULL:

```
void* print (void* data)
{
    cout << "Hi" << endl;
    return NULL;
}
```

Not sure about the high sleeps either right the threads exit, which is unnecessary and would hold the threads from exiting. Probably not something you wanted.

Comment: Thanks P.P. It worked for me. I thought the created threads are  running fast hence i could not see the print even, hence i put sleep time in the print function. didnt think about the main thread.

Comment: @Jonathan No. The problem would remain the same. `pthread_detach()` simply tells the pthreads library that no one is waiting on it and its resources can be freed immediately once the thread returns/exits. But it can't help if the main thread exits (via `exit`) or returns from main (in that case, the process dies).